# Wordpress get custom post type tag list

Tags: wordpress, tags, custom-post-type

Trying to get the tag list for a single custom post type, have tried get_the_tag_list() and implementing the following, I only get the tags for the current post, not the whole lot for the custom post type.

My code is:

```
 $terms = get_terms( 'blog' ); print_r($terms); - to see if I get any output from the array, all I get is:  

 WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please add how you add tags to your custom post type. If you use a custom taxonomy for tags, what is that taxonomy called. What is your post type called. From the error you can see that the custom taxonomy `blog` does not exists

Comment: The custom post type is called "blog"

Comment: `get_terms` expect that the first argument is a taxonomy, not post type